# How to prove that the equation $x^5-1102x^4-2015x=0$ has at least three real roots?

Tags: calculus

I've already used the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that there is at least one real root.
$f(1)=-3116<0$
$f(-1)=912>0$
Using IVT to $N=0,$ there exists $c \in (-1,1)\;$ such that $\;f(c)=0.$
I can use Rolle's Theorem to show that there is at least $2$ real roots, but how do I show that the equation has **at least** three real roots?

Comment: Just notice that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=-2015<0$.

Answer (score 0):

At $x=o$ the polynomial has a root which is your third real root.

[See this if you need further hint](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5-1102x%5E4-2015x%3D0)